# Date formats in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am uploading a .csv file in pl/sql developer using text importer.
The file which I upload has a column(Effective date) with the date format of '3/1/2009'.  but after uploading , when I query , it is displaying as '1/3/2009'.

I have to write update query to correct it. but it is not possible if I have huge records with different dates.

Can somebody tell me why the date is updating wrongly, and how to correct it.

Comment: Did you update a date field with a converted string? maybe it's the same date but in different format, that is you have a different date decoding/encoding schema

Comment: You mean in .csv file through format cells

Comment: yes, when you import a text file, all is text, next some tools like yours convert this text into an internal data type like date or number. In this case for dates you either have a default format or you are supplying one. Is this you case?

Comment: mine has a default format (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: and you default date format in pl/sql developer? is it the same?

Comment: yes And there is one more field start date that follows same format like effective date and it is displaying correctly after uploading

Comment: are the conversion formats during the text importer the same for the two fields?

Comment: So in the end you have two fields with same convertion format, same display format, same data inside and different results?!

Comment: Have you tried to put the exact same string in both fields and see if they return different results during querying? Next, if you see them as different, can you use to_char to demonstrate they are indeed two different dates?

Comment: ok... i will try and let u know

Comment: and the data type in your table is what? string or date?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is automatically converting from a string/varchar to a date data type. It's using `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in your environment to convert back and forth between dates and text. You can change that format for your session with this statement: `alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY';`. Chose format appropriate for your data, 'MM/DD/YYYY' seems to be what you need. Other ways to change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` are described here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format.htm. Most probably you don't want to permanently set it in your environment but rather set it for the current active session and it will be reset once you disconnect. I don't have PL/SQL Developer here to try but it might also have a setting like that in the menu somewhere.